# What is tag <view> in layout xml used for?

Tags: android, android-layout

I notice that there is a tag `<view>`(not `<View>`) which can be used in Android layout xml. When I add such a tag in a layout xml, the app can be successfully compiled but crashes when running. So what is this `<view>` used for?

Comment: "I notice that there is a tag <view>(not <View>) which can be used in Android layout xml" -- can you point to someplace where either this is documented or official Android code (samples, AOSP apps, etc.) uses it?

Comment: @CommonsWare In Android Studio you can see there is a selection named `view` in the popup menu when you type `<view`.

Comment: That might be indicative of an Android Studio bug, then. Again, can you point to someplace where either this is documented or official Android code (samples, AOSP apps, etc.) uses it?

Comment: @CommonsWare: I found some docementation here:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/package-summary.html and in xml the view description says: "A view tag whose class attribute names the class to be instantiated"

Comment: @DroidMind: That is not documentation for a `<view>` element.

Comment: there is no <view> tag in android , you must got an error Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #n: Error inflating class null (that means an invalid attribute in your xml)

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't see any code uses this tag. I am just curious why   Android Studio provides such a indicative selection if it is useless.

Comment: @NibhaJain so this is just a bug in Android Studio?

Comment: My guess is that it is an Android Studio bug.

Comment: view selection appears in eclipse also

Comment: I can not see the view in Palette .. in studio yes but it is in eclipse

Comment: Interestingly view has an attribute called class which lists only customViews when I use quick completion                                                                                                <view android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    class="pkgname.ui.yourCustomView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"/>

Comment: ant it says "A view tag whose class attribute names the class to be instantiated"

Comment: yes the same i did @DroidMind , able to successfully run the app with a class button <view
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            class="Button" />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`view` is an alternative way for specifying a view to inflate. You need to combine it with `class` attribute to specify the class name.

This is "useful" if your view class is an inner class and you cannot use something with a `$` in the tag name in XML. (Having inner classes as `View`s you inflate is not a very good idea though.)

For example:

```
<view class="your.app.full.package.Something$InnerClass" ... />
```

Reference: http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#696

Comment: If the view is an inner class, how will it be instantiated without an instance of outer class?

Comment: Needs to be static, of coutse.

Answer (score -1):

View is widget of android that is use to add any kind of view.Like in problems when we use scrollView in a activity and at bottom of activity there is buttons ,That time we add view to looks better.We can set any kind of color to View .
for exp 
    
  This will make a View of 20dp height.

Comment: I mean `<view>` the letter 'v' is in lower case.